# Credit where credit is due - Questions with 0 votes but 1+ answers

Tags: discussion, voting

Perhaps this has been asked before but I haven't managed to find it, so forgive me if this is a duplicate.

This site in particular on the network has a reputation for giving virtually zero credit to people who ask questions, even if they're good ones (don't lie, you're guilty of it too!) Scrolling through the activity feed you can see dozens of questions that have one or more answers, and these are legitimate questions with legitimate answers, but zero votes on the question. If a question is worth answering, instead of just commenting, is it not also worth upvoting? I can't tell you how many times I've Googled an odd problem and found the exact question and answer on SO, and the answer might even have dozens of votes, but the question has a score of 0 or 1.

Here's the meat behind that problem. It's not just a call for "let's all be nicer". It actually becomes an issue for people, especially new users, who have questions that may not be "top-notch" but are still valid. To use my profile for an example, I have asked a lot of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011755/thanby?tab=questions&sort=votes) that got valid answers, and while some of them are from back when I was an uber-noob they at least got answered and not closed or anything like that. Yet all but 2 of them have 1 vote or less (the vast majority being 0). The problem here is not that I care about my score. It's that because of this record, my account frequently gets put "on notice" for having too many "poorly-received" questions (those with 1 vote or less).

Surely this is not an isolated incident. I see so many other questions from low-ranking accounts that get answered but never voted on or even given suggestions for improvement. I'd have to believe I'm not the only one who is trying to participate and getting shot down by the site's culture.

So what can be done about it? The solutions I can see would either be to shift the culture somehow (preferable but probably impossible), or change the algorithm that detects "under-performing" accounts so they don't get punished for this. Perhaps there are other solutions too? I'm tempted to serially-upvote all these lonesome questions but I know I'd probably get banned for that.

Anyways, what possible solutions do we have to this? Has anyone else observed this as a problem?

Comment: `If a question is worth answering, instead of just commenting, is it not also worth upvoting?` No, not necessarily.

Comment: Good questions are typically rewarded by getting an answer. If you're lucky.

Comment: It's unfortunately possible for a not useful/low quality/poorly researched question to receive an answer. They often receive multiple very quickly.

Comment: @TomášZato In that case I have asked tons of good questions. But my account still gets put "on notice". That doesn't add up.

Comment: Most (non-bad) answers don't get any votes either, except maybe from the asker of the question.

Comment: *and these are legitimate questions* That phrase has been abused so much there is literally nowhere on the doll that hasn't been touched.

Comment: @Glorfindel This is true, but much less of a problem because your account doesn't get suspended for having too many 0-vote answers

Comment: You don't get suspended for a string of 0 vote questions either.

Comment: @Glorfindel Twice in the past I've been notified of that. When I went to ask a new question a warning popped up saying "Your recent questions have not been well-received (1 vote or less). If this continues your account is subject to suspension." (something to that effect)

Comment: @thanby If you have a demonstrated history of not providing useful answers you're unable to post more answers, likewise, if you have a demonstrated history of not asking good questions, you're not able to ask more questions.

Comment: @thanby "[...] a warning popped up saying [...]" -- I suspect that the warning, if it directly mentions votes or scores at all, actually refers to -1 score or less, rather than "1 vote or less", though I can't be fully sure of that (I have never seen the warning itself, and none of the quotes/screenshots I have found in Meta mention votes or scores directly). It would be astonishing if questions with +1 score were considered as not well-received for suspension purposes.

Comment: Wait, what? How on earth can this be a duplicate of a post about imminent question/answer bans?

Comment: Yeah I am actually suggesting we change it somehow. That guy's question got answered pretty thoroughly when someone did the math for him, but in my case it's not very clear, and that's not what my question is about anyways.

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 phases of question lifetime - initial answering and subsequent visit from searches.

During initial answering it is very hard to estimate usefulness of the question, only quality (MCVE, research shown, readable text). So at that stage questions get usually small amount of votes (under 10 positive or negative). Some questions also get upvotes for being extremely interesting (rare case).

During second stage (let's say week after being asked) people searching for answer to particular problem will fine question from search engines and presumable upvote if they found it useful. There is essentially no limit how many votes question gets at that stage (100+ is not unusual).

What you can do about it: vote on quality when answering, vote on usefulness if found question while researching your problem. If asking question that is essentially useful just to you - make sure question is of high initial quality as it is less likely such post get many visitors in the future.

Comment: This is a good general guideline, but it's not helpful to new users who don't necessarily understand what a "high-quality" question is. If we want questions to be perfectly written, users should be handed a guidebook or some examples first, because the current method of "hey maybe you should check out the FAQ" isn't doing a great job.

Comment: Also random search hits can't vote unless they make an account, so 90%+ of the people who come across your question won't contribute anyway.

Comment: But how much of that "isn't doing a great job" is the fault of the FAQ, and how much is it the fault of the lazy-ass people who don't bother to read or apply it? Going off my own experiences, I know which one my money's on. I don't believe it's that hard to ask a good question, people generally just don't like being told they haven't done something right, so they become indignant and resistant to the very concept of improvement. If you can find a way to fix that attitude, great, let's do it! Then we can talk about the attitudes of the volunteer experts giving their time up for free....

Comment: @thanby Users *are* told up front that the site has strict quality standards, and given lots of information on what those standards are and how to ask good questions.  People ignore that information anyway, because they don't care, they just want Teh Codez given to them.